Adding ListViewItem from text changed event in Kotlin
If the user types in ListViewItem text: "Add new item" I want to add a new item.
This is my code so far:
class DataModel internal constructor(
    var checked: Boolean,
    var itemDesc: String?,
)

class CustomAdapter(private val dataSet: ArrayList<*>, mContext: Context) :
    ArrayAdapter<Any?>(mContext, R.layout.layout2, dataSet) {

    private class ViewHolder {
        lateinit var checkBox: CheckBox
        lateinit var textInput: TextView
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return dataSet.size
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): DataModel {
        return dataSet[position] as DataModel
    }

    override fun getView(
        position: Int,
        convertView: View?,
        parent: ViewGroup,
    ): View {
        var convertView = convertView
        val viewHolder: ViewHolder
        val result: View

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = ViewHolder()

            convertView =
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.layout2, parent, false)
            viewHolder.checkBox =
                convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox)
            viewHolder.textInput =
                convertView.findViewById(R.id.textInput)

            result = convertView
            convertView.tag = viewHolder
        } else {
            viewHolder = convertView.tag as ViewHolder
            result = convertView
        }

        return result
    }
}


What is ListViewItem?

I am a newbie at cotlin so my naming can be inappriopriate. I think about ListView item, as you look at DataModel class in my code. ListView item has two fields checkbox, and text field (i didnt attached xml to my code but you can imagine it from code).

How much I understand ,to achieve adding a new item to the ListView when the user types "Add new item", you can implement a TextWatcher on the editText  When the text is changed and matches the specified string, you can add a new item to your data set and notify the adapter to update the ListView
here is the code :

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var customAdapter: CustomAdapter
private val dataSet = ArrayList()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    customAdapter = CustomAdapter(dataSet, this)
    listView.adapter = customAdapter

    // Assuming editText is the EditText where the user types
    editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            // Check if the text matches "Add new item"
            if (s.toString().equals("Add new item", ignoreCase = true)) {
                // Add a new item to the data set
                dataSet.add(DataModel(false, "New Item"))
                // Notify the adapter that the data set has changed
                customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                // Clear the EditText
                editText.text.clear()
            }
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}
    })
}

}

You did it from Activity level, it is possible to do it from class level. In may code CustomAdapter is a class, and I try to define such behavior for class. CustomAdapter class knows dataSet, but I dont know how to get it, and use in my task.

I tried your code but I cant solve my problem. New Item doesnt appear. I dont know if code is wrong or I do something wrong.
